# Why is this list not being displayed correctly in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I can't figure out why this [list](http://ada.kiexpro.com/html/about.html) is not displaying properly in IE7.

The website: http://ada.kiexpro.com/html/about.html

The background image is covered by the div below and the div in the bottom is not displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `z-index` of `div#aboutbutton` to `2`. So, it will not be hidden under the `div#abouttop`. It should solve the problem

Comment: Hey janoCheon, I just edited the answer, instead of making div#abouttop 0, make div#aboutbutton 2.